# Scaling a mesh properly according to April Tag Board

Tags: transforms

I am trying to create a synthetic dataset using [BlenderProc](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc) which makes use of Blender (3.5.1 in Ubuntu 22.04). On top of that I am using [BlenderProc2_Cobot](https://github.com/yangfei4/BlenderProc2_Cobot) which leverages BlenderProc. The idea is throwing object(s) of interest onto an April Tag board. What happens is the items of interest in author's repo is confidential, so I found something similar from this link. I tried scaling it in Blender to 0.001 and 0.01 but it either happens to be so small or ends up with collision or not being spawn due to various constraints. So is there an in between?

[image]

Here is an example of what happens if I make the female USB scale to 0.001.

Here's the item (scaled down already) opened again in Blender (I removed two of its parts -- smaller parts):
[image]

Followup questions would be:

1. How can I know how much I have scaled down the obj file from the original file? Is there an Ubuntu command/script for this?
2. Based on the size of board, is there a way to figure this?
   Here is the April Tag board object files: https://github.com/yangfei4/BlenderProc2_Cobot/tree/main/CAD_model

Here's the [female USB obj file](https://www.traceparts.com/en/product/rs-components-amphenol-fci-dual-port-right-angle-through-hole-type-a-usb-connector-socket-to-socket?CatalogPath=RS_COMPONENTS%3APSF_435862&Product=10-17082010-099135) I downloaded (you need an account for free download in obj format).

Here's what the tag board looks like:
[image]

Ideally, I want size ratio to be something like this:
https://github.com/yangfei4/Sim2real/blob/main/figures/synthetic.jpg
[image]

Also, I used this part of Blender for scaling along all three axis to either of 0.001 or 0.01. Basically, how do you go about knowing the proper size/scale given an April Tag board?

[image]

To clarify further, when I scale differently, I can't see all of the board (while the original author is able to)

[image]